# Interpreting a Phase Diagram?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, phase

[image]

The correct answer (that is false) is A) however can someone please explain why the other options would be true and why it is in fact possible to compress a solid to produce a liquid?

Comment: Do you mean by reference to the provided diagram (from which all the true answers are clearly true)?  As for how you compress a solid to produce a liquid, one clear answer would be that the liquid is denser than the solid forms, and thus is preferred under high enough pressure.  An example is lithium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us go through this step-by-step:

> 1. **A**: A is undeniably false because if we pick a point on the solid side of the graph and add pressure to it, the point eventually
>      becomes the liquid.
> 2. **B**: B is true because the *triple point temperature* is where they all intersect, and the temperature there is less than the *critical point
>      temperature*.
> 3. **C**: You have to understand that C is a ***can*** question; it is true because you can form a gas or a liquid.
> 4. **D**: As you can see, where the substance changes phase is below **300 K**, so we can assume that this one is also true.
> 5. **E**: The liquid will boil when the  vapor pressure equals the pressure. The line from the triple point to the critical point is
>      sloping up. So this is also true.
>
> **That leaves us with A as the only false answer.**

You might want to review some concepts on phase changes and pressures.

However just to add as a side note, this question kind of seems like a homework question, you might want to add more detail and your process, so that people ***can*** take the time to answer you back. **Showing some effort, gives a cause for others to care.**

Thanks.

**Sources**: [Jon Custer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/5677/jon-custer) helped find out E.

Comment: For E remember that the liquid will boil when it's vapor pressure equals the applied pressure. The line from the triple point to the critical point is sloping up.

Comment: Yup, thank you. I will add that into my answer.